# Organizing functions into modules based on choice

Tags: python

I have 2 Python modules (e.g. A.py & B.py) that have the same function names (the implementation is different though). A third module (C.py) has a function that requires the functions in A or B, depending on user choice.

A fourth module (D.py) will import either A or B, and then C.

How do I correctly setup the modules and imports?

```py
# module A.py
def write():
    print('A')

# module B.py
def write():
    print('B')

# module C.py
def foo():
    write()

# module D.py (main executed module)
if choiceA:
    import A
    import C
else:
    import B
    import C

C.foo()
```

Comment: I suspect, that your proposed mapping to modules is not optimum. It seems easier to solve using a class hierarchy, where C sintantiates to appropriate class according to a constructor argument, which is determined by the user choice in D.

Answer (score 1):

Not much really.

Module A.py:

```py
def write():
    print('A')
```

Module B.py

```py
def write():
    print('B')
```

Module C.py

```py
def foo(choice):
    if choice == 'A':
        import A
        A.write()
    elif choice == 'b':
        import B
        B.write()
    else:
        #whatever
```

module D.py

```py
choice = input('Enter choice:   ')
import C
C.foo(choice)
```

Comment: That works, but there's really too much boilerplate code. It could be much more elegant with classes, as guidot suggested in the comments.

Comment: Yes, but I think @fabio was trying to find a working solution, not elegant one.

Comment: The idea of StackOverflow is to maintain a database of questions and answers for everyone to use, when they encounter the same kind of problem which was previously solved here. Therefore, your answer is not just for fabio - it is for everyone. The quality of the answer is independent of fabio's expectations. My comment is also not just for you, it is for everyone, warning that a better solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a basic case of a [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Instead of doing a double-import and implicitly expecting module `C` to get the right module, you should just explicitly pass the appropriate selection for it to call.

Using modules `A` and `B` as before:

```
# module C.py
def foo(writer):
    writer.write()

# module D.py
import A
import B
import C

if choiceA:
  my_writer = A
elif choiceB:
  my_writer = B

C.foo(my_writer)
```

This will also continue to work exactly the same way if you choose to define `A`, `B`, and `C` as a class hierarchy instead of modules.